# c# roles multiple providers cant call function

Tags: c#, roleprovider

My role providers:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="ConnectionString1" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider,System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=xxx"/>
        <add connectionStringName="ConnectionString2" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProviderProduction" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider,System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=xxx"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

When I try to call AddUserToRole:

```
var roleProviderProduction = Roles.Providers["AspNetSqlRoleProviderProduction"];
roleProviderProduction.AddUserToRole(username, role);
```

I get this error:

> Error 59  'System.Web.Security.RoleProvider' does not contain a
>   definition for 'AddUserToRole' and no extension method 'AddUserToRole'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Security.RoleProvider'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: Isn't the method called `AddUsersToRoles`?

Comment: no: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You are mixing up [RoleProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles(v=vs.110).aspx). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up [RoleProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles(v=vs.110).aspx). While there is a method [AddUserToRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole(v=vs.110).aspx) in `Roles`, `RoleProvider` only has [AddUsersToRoles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.adduserstoroles(v=vs.110).aspx).

You should use

```
var  roleProviderProduction = Roles.Providers["AspNetSqlRoleProviderProduction"];
roleProviderProduction.AddUsersToRoles(new string[]{username}, new string[]{role});
```

or

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(username, role);
```

Comment: why? AddUserToRole is not the same function with AddUserToRole. Why I can't use AddUserToRole with specific (not the default) role provider? Sorry I am quite new to this

Comment: Because it is not defined in `RoleProvider` class. Sure it would have been possible for Microsoft to define a method for a single user in a single role, they obviously decided not to do so. Anyway, it's no problem to wrap your parameters in to `string[]` and call `AddUsersToRoles`.